# How to align everything in a row inside a card?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have the following card, the code is given below. I want to align everything in a row, for now it comes one below the other. Is there any option to align everything in single row rather than three,

```
<div class="container">
            <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
                <div class="row" style={{ width: "300px", marginTop: "40px", marginLeft: "70px", height: "450px" }}>
                    <FormControl variant="outlined">
                        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-outlined-label" >Choose Module Type</InputLabel>
                        <Select style={{ marginBottom:"20px"}}
                            name="name"
                            labelId="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
                            id="demo-simple-select-outlined"
                            onChange={handleDropdownChange}
                            label="TypeList"
                        >
                            {
                                dropdown.map(options =>
                                    <MenuItem value={options["moduleType"]} >{options["moduleType"]}</MenuItem>
                                )}
                        </Select>
                        <TextField 
                            style={{ marginTop: "10px", marginBottom:"20px" }}
                            id="outlined-helperText"
                            label="Module Name"
                            onChange={handleChangeModuleName}
                            variant="outlined"
                        />
                        <TextField
                            style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}
                            id="outlined-helperText"
                            label="Course Duration"
                            onChange={handleChangeDuration}
                            variant="outlined"
                        />
                        <div style={{ margin: "auto", marginTop: "20px" }}>
                        <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">ADD</Button>
                      </div>
                    </FormControl>
                </div>
            </form>
         </div>
```

Please help :)
Thank you

Comment: CSS flexbox should work here as they can make them centered vertically and horizontally, read more about flexbox here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

just simply add display:'flex' to your row class

```
.row{
     display:'flex'
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> A flex container expands items to fill available free space or shrinks them to prevent overflow. Most importantly, the flexbox layout is direction-agnostic as opposed to the regular layouts (block which is vertically-based and inline which is horizontally-based).

Try using `display: flex;`. That will keep all items in a row.

```
.row {
    display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get in touch with the flex property.
Add in your css stylesheet this

```
.row {
    display: flex;
}
```

Overall try avoiding inline-stlyes (using css properties right in your html file). Instead use an external stylesheet (you can call it something like style.css). You can link it to your html file by using this line

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
```